# Rails + HTTParty : Expecting JSON data in the body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, httparty

I want to integrate the Routific API into a Rails application. I made my request with HTTParty but I get the following message {"error"=>"Expecting JSON data in the body"}

I don't understand... I am sending the json in the body. Please check my code below.

Thanks for your help

Julien

```
file = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/demo.json")

api_key = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ODE3M2ZiNTk1NzRjZTFiMmZhNWEwNTAiLCJpYXQiOjE0Nzc5MTg2NDZ9.extq0nKtPGwj6VXxMpj9u8uapasKVSorWeTBFW7HgOE"

headers = {
  "Content-Type:" => "application/json",
  'authorization'=> 'bearer ' + api_key
}

@results = HTTParty.post("https://api.routific.com/v1/vrp", 
:headers => headers,
:body => file.to_json)
```

Answer (score 2):

you added invalid headers

it should be "Content-Type" instead of "Content-Type:" (without colon)

Comment: Oh my God... Indeed Thank you!

Can you please vote for my question so that I can recommend your answer (I don't have enough points)

Comment: @JulienP : I think you don't need any points to accept my answer. [Please check this out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)